# Google Sheets Checkboxes with formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHHLrLdQBRgTliO_ZFmTUSTdkkWla8Lf982lG0MwJ0M/edit?usp=sharing) of my work. The problem is, I'm having trouble with my checkboxes right now. The checkboxes are visible on my spreadsheet, but when I tried to print it, the checkboxes were not printed.

I'm using this formula: `=IF(VLOOKUP($C$2,StudData,25,0)="YES","☑","☐")`

Should I use the DATA VALIDATION or CHECKBOX options? How can I indicate that when the data is "YES" or "NO," the checkboxes will be marked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION THAT I MADE:**

I tried using the DATA VALIDATION with the criteria of checkbox.

[image]

And then I modified the formula to `=IF(VLOOKUP($C$2,StudData,25,0)="YES","YES","NO")`.